# Why won't the Xamarin build system find com.google.firebase.messaging?

Tags: c#, firebase, push-notification, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am attempting to add Firebase based push notifications to my Xamarin.Forms Android app as described in the Xamarin developer guide here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/data-and-cloud-services/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm/.

However, as soon as I extend FirebaseMessagingService, I receive this error: "error: package com.google.firebase.messaging does not exist"

[Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFUi5.png)

I have added the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base and Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging Nuget packages as described in the tutorial and can see the references in my Visual Studio project. I have downloaded the example project that goes with the tutorial and it builds correctly as does a brand new project I created.

I have struggled with this for several days and am not sure what else I can try to resolve this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: What template do you use when you create a `Xamarin.Android` project?

Comment: We used the "Cross-Platform App (Xamarin.Forms)" Visual Studio template.  The project is setup to use a PCL for common code between iOS and Android

Comment: Would you mind share a basic demo to reproduce this problem? I need more information to find out the reason, that's really appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been able to recreate the issue when starting a new project.  A brand new project and the Xamarin example project both build correctly, even when I add in the complete set of nugget packages being used on the problematic project

Comment: When I use `Bottom Navigation App` android template I got the same error, but once I create a `Xamarin.Android` project with another template, the error is gone. If you don't mind share the problematic project that will be really appreciated!